# WordPress get_the_tag as list

Tags: wordpress, tags

```
 <?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

This puts a space between the tags that it outputs, but how do I put something BEFORE each tag so I can wrap them in `<li>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "the_tags()" instead? It might be better for what you need.

You can use some tags to make it look like a list (or whatever you like). Check this link for more, and always refer to the codex:
[Working with the_tags() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

From this link we have the following example:

```
<?php the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>
```

Anoter great reference to you is the [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is a great resource for WP-related functions. You could modify one of the example functions on the [`get_the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) reference page to output a list of tags:

```
function list_tags() {
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
            echo "<li>{$tag->name}</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

Or use `the_tags` built-in function to wrap a list of tags in a list:

```
<?php the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>
```

Comment: That function just gives me a server error.

And the reason I'm using get_the_tags instead of the_tags is because I don't want them displaying as links.

Comment: If can still use the_tags and use strip_tags(); passing a second value for the tags you want to keep...